# How to show XYZ coordinates without the 'Fn' key?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My keyboard doesn't have an Fn key so I can't get the coordinates to show up. I don't know how to get into the multiplayer settings and Shift + F3 doesn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't it just the F2/F3 key? (I don't remember which is which, one takes a screenshot the other shows coordinates) You shouldn't need the Fn key or the Shift key.

Comment: @Ben you'll need an Fn key if you have a compact Keyboard where you need to press and hold Fn then a number key (where F# is normally printed on so `-` is F11 and `=` becomes F12) however you are right you shouldn't need to use Shift if you have the regular F# Keys unless you've altered the key bindings

Comment: Been a while since I've played Minecraft, but can't you just remap the coordinates overlay to a different key in the Options menu?

Comment: Does your keyboard have an `f Lock` button like mine does?

Comment: "(FuNction key) A keyboard modifier key that works like a Shift key to activate a second function on a dual-purpose key." So the FN key is actually just a modifier key, like shift or control. By itself it should not have a purpose.

Answer (score 5):

**Just press F3**.

If your keyboard does not have <kbd>Fn</kbd>, then odds are, <kbd>F3</kbd> works as normal. No keyboard manufacturer would require <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> without providing a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: clearly you do not own an older mac

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on a Mac. On there, you should open System Preferences, go in Keyboard and enable the use of Function keys as delfault actions. I had to do this too on my Mac!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for going to the coordinate screen, such as:

1. Press F3
2. Go to Options, click controls and change the key needed
3. You may have a 'f lock' key . Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If f3 does not work, go to Mac system preferences, keyboard, then tick "use f keys as normal" go back to your game and hit f3.  Done

Comment: Nowhere does the asker indicate that this problem is on a mac.

Answer (score -2):

The Mac keyboards do not have the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button and the <kbd>F3</kbd> key is used to manage your different windows. I fear there may be no way to access coordinates on this situation.

Comment: They do. It's on the bottom left for macbooks and the [compact keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ErgQC.jpg) and left of `home` for the [full keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o8wIW.png).